# Wiki Application With A Reputation System

Tags: looking-for-a-script, wiki, reputation

I'm really impressed with Stack Exchange's concept of reputation (you gain reputation as you post, and the more you post, the more privileges you get), and I want to apply the concept to a wiki that I am building.

Does anyone know of a php wiki that has a concept of privileges/reputation similar to Stack Exchange? I'm not necessarily looking for something *identical* to SE, I'm just looking for a wiki application that gives users more privileges the more they contribute *positively* to the wiki (SE has down votes, the wiki should have some way of identifying negative contributions too). The privileges should be category based, so the more active you are in a specific category or page, the more privileges you get for that category. There should also be site wide privileges as well, though those should be harder to access than the category privileges.

*NOTE: If it is not possible to get category wide privileges and site wide privileges, I will be OK with just category wide privileges or just site wide privileges.*

I should be able to change the requirements for each privilege, through a administration panel or through editing a file (some wiki applications don't have administration interfaces).

Does anyone have a script or a solution that will do this? If the script uses something similar to reputation to determine how much a user has positively contributed to the site, then that is OK too.

*Please Note: I am looking for a way to rate individual user contributions, not a way to rate the quality of an entire page.*

Comment: SE reputation is only given to you by other people, not based on activity. If you increased reputation (or whatever its called) by editing, then you could cheat the system by simply doing lots of editing. Where you thinking of reputation given by others, or given by what you've done?

Comment: I'm thinking of reputation given by others.

Comment: You should be aware that on wikis, generally poor contributions/contributors are removed. You can see the value of the contribution by how much of it is left in the page.

Answer (score 2):

[MediaWiki](http://mediawiki.org) has some extensions that do rating this including [W4G rating bar](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aW4G_Rating_Bar). If you can't find a wiki that does it out of the box you could hack that extension and combine it with the built in privileges system to do what you want. Or you could give a [bounty](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Bounty) for someone to do it for you (though one link on that page doesn't work and the Facebook page is pretty quiet).

Comment: I don't think that plugin allows you to rank an individuals contribution to a page.

Comment: Actually you're right. It ranks the quality of the whole page, which could have been created by several people. To do ranking people are going to have to look at the contribution someone made (maybe by using the page history function) and then rate that.

Comment: Are there any plugins that do that?

Comment: I couldn't see any. Rating people rather than content doesn't seem to be a common concept.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out [Question2Answer](http://www.question2answer.org/) yet ? It does have a reputation system, is in php and can be integrated within a wiki. However, as far as I know, the reputation does not grant additional privileges, like in SE.

Comment: Does the reputation work on the wiki, or just in the Q&A?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't actually a solution, it's more of a way that someone could implement this if they were interested in doing so:

1. A user rates a wiki page. He either gives it a thumbs up or a thumbs down.
2. The wiki software looks through the page history to determine how much of the page was written by different authors. Let's say that user one has contributed 50% of the characters in the page, and that users two and three have contributed 25% of the characters in the page.
3. The wiki software awards 50% of the points that a thumbs up is worth to user 1, and 25% of the points to users two and three. If a thumbs up is worth 10 points, than user 1 get's 5 points of reputation, and users two and three get 2.5 points of reputation.
4. You can do the same thing with down votes, only you take away points instead of adding them.

*NOTE: the rating system only analyzes how much of the content users wrote in the current version of this page at the time the rating was given. If user 4 also contributed to the page, but then users one, two, and three completely removed his contributions, user 4 will not get any reputation points.*

*NOTE: if user 5 comes along, and then edits the page, user 5 will only get reputation if someone upvotes the page when some of her original content is displayed on the page. **Again, reputation is only given to users whose content is appearing at the current version of the page at the time the rating was given.***

*NOTE: it would be a good idea to allow for users to re-rate the page if any edits are made to it, so that they can downvote the page if a user forgets to cite a claim or something in an edit that they made after the vote was issued.*

BTW if anyone was willing to create a wiki plugin/script that did this, then that would be great. If there is already a wiki plugin/script that does this, please post it in the comments.